# Trying to use react to trigger different components with the same function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a an accordion using React but and I receive my data from a Json API which I dynamically use to make the table. All that works.
However when I try to make the toggleHidden function, it opens every single view instead of the one I just clicked on. How can I target a specific component when clicking instead of just using **this**

```
<Table striped bordered condensed hover>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Asset #</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Person</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Room</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Patches</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Java</th>
      <th>AACV</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>

   {this.state.items.map((data, key) => {
     return (
       <tbody>
         <tr 
           id={data.name} 
           onClick=`{this.toggleHidden.bind(this)} 
         >`
           <td>{data.name}</td>
           <td >{data.height}</td>
           <td>{data.mass}</td>
           <td>{data.gender}</td>
           <td >{data.birth_year}</td>
           <td>{data.eye_color}</td>
           <td >{data.birth_year}</td>
           <td>{data.eye_color}</td>
           <td >{data.birth_year}</td>
           <td>{data.eye_color}</td>
         </tr>
         <td 
           className={data.name} 
           colSpan="10"
         > 
          {!this.state.isHidden && <Filled/>}
         </td>
       </tbody>
     )
   })}
 </Table>



 toggleHidden (e) {
    this.setState({
        isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
    })
}
```

Comment: You've got a `<td/>` outside of the `<tr/>`. Might want to fix that.

Comment: It ruins the format and thats outside the scope of my immediate problems

Comment: Might want to inspect the dom and see what the browser actually renders (The browser is fixing your  code).

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to make nested state for each key that means

```js
const { Table, Icon } = semanticUIReact;

const ITEMS = [
  {
    asset: "Asset 1",
    description: "Description"
  },
  {
    asset: "Asset 2",
    description: "Description2"
  }
];
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { items: ITEMS };
    this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Table striped bordered condensed selectable>
        <Table.Header>
          <Table.Row>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Asset</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Description</Table.HeaderCell>
          </Table.Row>
        </Table.Header>

        <Table.Body>{this.state.items.map(this.renderRow)}</Table.Body>
      </Table>
    );
  }

  renderRow(data, key) {
    return (
      <Table.Row onClick={() => this.toggleHidden(key)}>
        <Table.Cell>{data.asset}</Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell textAlign="right">
          {this.state[key] ? "This is hidden" : data.description}
        </Table.Cell>
      </Table.Row>
    );
  }

  toggleHidden(key) {
    this.setState({
      [key]: !this.state[key]
    });
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.1/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui-react@0.79.1/dist/umd/semantic-ui-react.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'isHidden' of undefined

Comment: @NEMS05 I've added full working snipped (please run in full mode)

Answer (score 0):

I Would suggest you to use the power of components.
Create component for row inside the table, something like this:

```
export default class Row extends React.Component {

 render() {
   const { data } = this.props;
         <tbody>
         <tr 
           id={data.name} 
           onClick=`{this.toggleHidden.bind(this)} 
         >`
           <td>{data.name}</td>
           <td >{data.height}</td>
           <td>{data.mass}</td>
           <td>{data.gender}</td>
           <td >{data.birth_year}</td>
           <td>{data.eye_color}</td>
           <td >{data.birth_year}</td>
           <td>{data.eye_color}</td>
           <td >{data.birth_year}</td>
           <td>{data.eye_color}</td>
         </tr>
         <td 
           className={data.name} 
           colSpan="10"
         > 
          {!this.state.isHidden && <Filled/>}
         </td>
       </tbody>
 }
 toggleHidden() {
  this.setState(state => ({
    isHidden: !state.isHidden 
}));
}
}
```

and in your main component do something like this:

```
<Table striped bordered condensed hover>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Asset #</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Person</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Room</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Patches</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Java</th>
      <th>AACV</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>

   {this.state.items.map((data, key) => <Row data={data} />}
 </Table>
```

it's more readable, it's more react style, and it's let each row to handle their own state

(there might be some syntax error, but the concept is working)

Good Luck!